# Why do variable prefixes in ruby allow omission of parenthesis in method invocations?

Tags: ruby, semantics

In The Ruby Programming Language by David Flanagan; Yukihiro Matsumoto, [they state that the variable prefixes ($, @, @@) are one price we pay for being able to omit parentheses around method invocations](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=rbY5mz-_VdQC&lpg=PA7&ots=10Wd8nk-uL&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q&f=false). Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Good question actually. I'm not sure that statement is even true, strictly speaking. I always thought the prefixes were to specify scope (i.e. local,instance,class,global) rather than distinguishing variables from methods (clearly local variable names are being distinguished from method calls by the interpreter).

Comment: When you ask about a specific reference, at least give a link to it if it is available online.

Comment: @sawa: [link](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=rbY5mz-_VdQC&lpg=PA7&ots=10Wd8nk-uL&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my immature opinion. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Suppose the instance variables don't have a `@` prefix, then how do we declare an instance variable?

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
    # Here foo is an instance variable
    self.foo = 'bar'
  end

  # Here foo is an instance method
  def foo
  end

  def bar
    # Call method. No doubt.
    self.foo()

    # Call method? Access instance variable?
    self.foo
  end
end
```

In the case above, the instance variable `foo` is initialized using the hypothetical syntax

```
self.foo = 'bar'
```

because we must have a way to tell the ruby interpreter that `foo` belongs to the current instance and is not a local variable.

Then in the method `bar`, if parentheses are not enforced in method invocation, how can the interpreter tell whether `self.foo` is a method invocation or an instance variable access?

Maybe we can let instance variables shadow instance methods when parentheses are missing, but this causes syntax inconsistency of the language itself. For example, from outside the `MyClass` definition:

```
obj = MyClass.new

# Call instance method
obj.foo
```

It's an instance method invocation because all instance variables are invisible from outside (at least without using meta programming). But the `self.foo` (without parentheses) in the method `bar` is an instance variable access. This syntax inconsistency may lead to bugs. Also, it brings difficulty in implementing the interpreter itself.

Then what about letting instance methods shadow instance variables? Then the programmers have to ensure the instance variable names don't collide with instance method names, otherwise the instance variables become inaccessible. It's very difficult if a class have a long ancestors chain because one must check collisions not only in the current class definition, but also in its ancestors, and this breaks encapsulation.

Either way, the price is much higher than adding a prefix to instance variables. For class and global variables, the situations are similar.

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at an example:

```
def foo
    10
end

p foo
#=> 10
foo = 'hi'
p foo
#=> hi
p foo()
#=> 10
```

If we define a local variable whose name is same as method name in the same scope, then, we lose the binding to method name as variable name takes precedence.  To disambiguate, one will be force to use parenthesis.

The book seems to elaborate about this phenomenon, and design decision taken to provide the flexibility wherein one need to use symbols like `@` to define instance variables so that respective accessor methods (`var` & `var=`) can be invoked without parenthesis, and one gets an impression that one is accessing the variable, even though in reality one is invoking a method.

> ... you’ll notice punctuation characters at the start of Ruby variable
>   names: global variables are prefixed with $, instance variables are
>   prefixed with @, and class variables are prefixed with @@. These
>   prefixes can take a little getting used to, but after a while you may
>   come to appreciate the fact that the prefix tells you the scope of the
>   variable. The prefixes are required in order to disambiguate Ruby’s
>   very flexible grammar. One way to think of variable prefixes is that
>   they are one price we pay for being able to omit parentheses around
>   method invocations.